# Least square method to fit data according to $g(x) = a - x + bx^2$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: computational-mathematics, least-squares, discrete-optimization

If I have a set of points $(x_i, f(x_i)) \in \mathbb{R^2} $ and I want to use the method of the the least square fitting to calculate the free parameters $a$ and $b$ of the function
$$
g(x) = a - x + bx^2
$$

By looking for the function $g$, one possible basis of function would be:
$$
\phi_1(x) = 1,  \phi_2(x)  = x^2
$$
And the missing function of $g$ would cause a translation of the linear space of the solutions. Is this correct?

I don't know to proceed with this exercise.
Could anyone give me a hint?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$h(x)=g(x)+x$$
First fit the function $h(x)$ for $a,b$ :
$$h(x)=a+bx^2$$
The LINEAR Least Mean Square Regression leads to approximate $a$ and $b$ :
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
  a  \\
  b
 \end{matrix}\right) \simeq
\left(\begin{matrix}
  n & \sum_{i=1} ^{i=n} x_i^2 \\
  \sum_{i=1} ^{i=n} x_i^2 & \sum_{i=1} ^{i=n} x_i^4 
 \end{matrix}\right)^{-1}
\left(\begin{matrix}
  \sum_{i=1} ^{i=n} h_i \\
  \sum_{i=1} ^{i=n} h_ix_i^2
 \end{matrix}\right)\quad \text{with}\quad h_i=f_i(x_i)+x_i$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have $n$ data points $(x_i,y_i)$ and you want to minimize
$$\text{SSQ}=\sum_{i=1}^n \big(a-x_i+b x_i^2-y_i\big)^2$$ Start defining two new variables$$z_i=y_i+x_i\qquad \text{and} \qquad  t_i=x_i^2$$ which make
$$\text{SSQ}=\sum_{i=1}^n \big(a+b\, t_i-z_i\big)^2$$  Setting the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial \text{ SSQ}}{\partial a}$ and $\frac{\partial \text{ SSQ}}{\partial b}$ equal to $0$, we have to solve the normal equations
$$n \,a +b \sum_{i=1}^n t_i=\sum_{i=1}^n z_i$$
$$a\sum_{i=1}^n t_i+b\sum_{i=1}^n t_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^n t_iz_i$$ that I shall rewrite as
$$n a +b S_t=S_z$$
$$a S_t+b S_{tt}=S_{tz}$$ and the exact solutions are
$$a=\frac{S_{tt}\, S_z-S_t \,S_{tz}}{n \,S_{tt}-S_t^2}\qquad \text{and} \qquad b=\frac{n\, S_{tz}-S_t\, S_z}{n \,S_{tt}-S_t^2}$$